# swagger.yaml :: How to generate properties with "Long" data type and "Timestamp" datatype?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I am using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to generate Java classes based on `swagger.yaml` spec.

I have added a property `phoneNum` in the `swagger.yaml` as below:

```
phoneNum:
    type: number
```

I am expecting it generate the property with `Integer` or `Long` datatype.
But it got generated as `BigDecimal phoneNum;`

As per the [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#numbers), it was mentioned to use `format: int64`

```
  phoneNum:
    type: number
    format: int64
```

But still, it ends up generating `private BigDecimal phoneNum;`

If anyone of you have faced similar issue and have a workaround, please share it here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to generate a `Long` property you have to use `integer` as type and `int64` as format

```
phoneNum:
    type: integer
    format: int64
```

Looking at [AbstractJavaCodegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java) I think there is no way to generate a `Timestamp` property.
The only available types are:

- `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`
- `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime`
- `org.joda.time.LocalDate`
- `org.joda.time.DateTime`
- `java.time.LocalDate`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime`
- `java.time.OffsetDateTime`
- `java.time.Instant` (added on Feb 2019)
- `java.util.Date`

Here's a way to convert OffsetDateTime to Timestamp

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
```